# Creating a db in runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Untill now I have used this code for creating a db dynamically:

```
var db = new MyEntities(db_name);
if (!db.DatabaseExists()) 
{
    db.CreateDatabase();
```

where MyEntities extends the ObjectContext class.

In my new application I have the same code, but now MyEntities extends the DbContext class and the DatabaseExists() and CreateDatabase() are not available.

How can I create a db now?

Comment: there is also `Database.CreateIfNotExists();` that you can run from your `DbContext`class, but I would still go with [No1_Melmans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27418398/238902) answer. That solution is more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the below code will execute a different stategy for creating a database, I believe it will run when a `DbContext` gets hit. so like `using (var context = new DbContext())`

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DbContext>());
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DbContext>());
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DbContext>());
```

These are pretty self explanatory. You can even override them so that you can add Seed data.

Put this in your `Global.asax`

As you can see, these are strongly typed classes. They take your inherited `DbContext` class.

So for instance:

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext {}

Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BlogContext>());
```

That above code will drop and create the database always using the `BlogContext` as a reference.

Comment: Yeah, I think its when you execute something in the `DbContext`, then it will start executing the SQL scripts, so then you will see Management Studio tables been created (obviously once you refresh your DB)

Comment: Can you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423193/createdatabaseifnotexists-creates-db-but-fails-to-create-a-relationship