# Why don't CreateDatabaseIfNotExists create a relationship although db gets created

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I create a db from my edmx file like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<myEntities>());
```

And the db is created. However, there is one recursive relationship missing. It is in the edmx, but not in the db. Why does it fail to create a recursive relationship and how can I fix it?

By recrusive relationship I mean a table that has a relationship with itself.

In the myEntities class, one of the fileds is this:

```
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

And in an auto-generated file:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Product1 = new HashSet<Product>();
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
        this.Ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Product1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Database.SetInitializer` is for creating the database when using code first, it does not look at your EDMX file.

Comment: @BenRobinson But it looks at myEntities, right?

Comment: Yes it looks at the context. It will build the database based on conventions and code first mappings for your entities. Mappings in your EDMX are not used.

Comment: @BenRobinson Can you check this question out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418303/creating-a-db-in-runtime

Comment: @BenRobinson It should still work I think. I added some code in the question, please see it.

Comment: It will "work" to the extent that it will build a database based on your models using code first conventions. It will ignore anything you have defined in your EDMX file. If you want to build a database using this method you should use code first. The model first why of building your database is to use the model builder within VS.

Comment: @BenRobinson I defin all my relationships on the same way. In the example from the question, the relationship Products-Ingredients exists in the created db, and Product-Product doesnt exist. I'm not talinking about the edmx file. Those are my models.